# Is there a way to toggle between two different rows using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use a toggle switch to switch between hiding two rows. I'd like to depress the button to have one row showing and the other row hidden and then when the button is not depressed have the other row showing and the first row be hidden.

I've created two toggle buttons to hide the rows separately but I'd really like to just have one toggle button to complete my task.

```
Private Sub ShowHideNexgenRent_Click()
Dim MyR As String
MyR = "17"

If ShowHideNexgenRent.Value Then
Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyR).Hidden = True
Else
Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyR).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub


Private Sub ShowHideNexgen_Click()
Dim MyR As String
MyR = "18"

If ShowHideNexgen.Value Then
Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyR).Hidden = True
Else
Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyR).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

This code gets allows me to hide both rows just not at the same time.

Comment: Is there any reason this is tagged with "html"?

Comment: Is it *always* rows 17 and 18 that you want to toggle, or do you want to toggle the row with the currently-selected-cell and the one below it, or ?

Comment: No there isn't a reason it's tagged with html. I'm just new to this and wanted to cast a wide net.

Comment: Right now it's just rows 17 and 18 that I want to toggle. In the future it might be different.